# Staying in Etosha Park, Namibia

Tags: bookings, camping, namibia

I've recently contacted [Etosha National Park](http://etoshanationalpark.org/), asking them to book 2 nights at their camping sites for our upcoming trip to Namibia. They've quickly got back with a quote, but in order to secure the booking I need to fill out a form, then fax or scan/email it to them. The scary thing is, form needs my credit card details, all of them, including number, CVV code, my signature, etc. This raises some questions:

1. Is that normal and safe thing to do? I've used official site and their contact form, so it does not look like an outright scam, but still giving my card details like so feels very uncomfortable.
2. If I don't proceed, is there any other way to stay overnight inside Etosha without violating any rules? Maybe these camps are not fully booked in early May, so we can just show up and hope to have a place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been to Etosha 3 years ago with a campervan.
We stayed at Olifantsrus and Halali.

During my time down there I had several occassions where I had to fill out all the details of my credit card on a form and submit it. It's commonplace. Sending it by email probably is, too.
If you went through https://www.etoshanationalpark.org/accommodation/enquire then you will be fine.

**Do not drive into Etosha without a booking!**
At the gate they are checking for your bookings. You have to adhere to your itinerary strictly. We were to leave the park at 2pm but only managed to leave at 3pm. We had to pay one more day on exit! So they will not even let you in without prebooked camp sites.

If night comes and you are not at a camp, you will be in big trouble anyway.